# Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

Once I execute the query I am getting the following error:

> Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Subquery returned more than 1
>   value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= ,
>
> > , >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

```
SELECT MAX(IL.INSLEND),n.ACTIONED, N.LEASID,n.BLDGID 
FROM note n 
INNER JOIN dbo.INSL il ON n.SEQNO=il.RECNUM 
INNER JOIN dbo.LEAS l ON l.BLDGID = n.BLDGID AND l.LEASID = n.LEASID
  AND n.REF1 = 'INSURAN' AND n.REF2= 'REMIND' OR n.ACTIONED <> 'C' 
  AND il.TABLEKEY = n.LEASID 
WHERE il.TABLEID='LEAS' AND il.TABLEKEY = L.LEASID 
GROUP BY n.LEASID, N.BLDGID, n.ACTIONED, IL.TABLEKEY, IL.TABLEID, L.LEASID
HAVING N.LEASID='083468' AND 
       (SELECT MAX(il.INSLEND) FROM dbo.INSL WHERE IL.TABLEKEY=L.LEASID AND IL.TABLEID='LEAS') < '2016-04-11'
```

Answer (score 0):

try this...

```
SELECT MAX(IL.INSLEND),n.ACTIONED, N.LEASID,n.BLDGID  FROM note n  INNER JOIN dbo.INSL il ON n.SEQNO=il.RECNUM  INNER JOIN dbo.LEAS l ON l.BLDGID = n.BLDGID AND l.LEASID = n.LEASID   AND n.REF1 = 'INSURAN' AND n.REF2= 'REMIND' OR n.ACTIONED <> 'C'    AND il.TABLEKEY = n.LEASID  WHERE il.TABLEID='LEAS' AND il.TABLEKEY = L.LEASID  GROUP BY n.LEASID, N.BLDGID, n.ACTIONED, IL.TABLEKEY, IL.TABLEID, L.LEASID HAVING N.LEASID='083468' AND MAX(il.INSLEND)< '2016-04-11'
```

Comment: error coming Column 'dbo.INSL.INSLEND' is invalid in the HAVING clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: i have edited the query. instead of Max(IL.INSLEND ),  try only IL.INSLEND .

Comment: still error coming Column 'dbo.INSL.INSLEND' is invalid in the HAVING clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
Msg 8121, Level 16, State 1, Line 10
Column 'dbo.INSL.INSLEND' is invalid in the HAVING clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: @DeepakJain, may i know edited query satisfies your requirement.. i thing     subquery conditions are satisfied main condition itself.. can you try this.

Answer (score 0):

Just add group by,to group same value

But also notice in your sub query `MAX(il.INSLEND)` you are aggregating the column of `dbo.INSL il` not the column of your subquery

```
( SELECT MAX(insl.INSLEND) 
  FROM dbo.INSL insl
  WHERE IL.TABLEKEY=L.LEASID AND IL.TABLEID='LEAS'
  GROUP BY (insl.INSLEND)
) < '2016-04-11'
```

Answer (score -1):

Try somethong like this:

```
SELECT MAX(IL.INSLEND),n.ACTIONED, N.LEASID,n.BLDGID 
FROM note n 
INNER JOIN dbo.INSL il ON n.SEQNO=il.RECNUM 
INNER JOIN dbo.LEAS l ON l.BLDGID = n.BLDGID AND l.LEASID = n.LEASID
  AND n.REF1 = 'INSURAN' AND n.REF2= 'REMIND' OR n.ACTIONED <> 'C' 
  AND il.TABLEKEY = n.LEASID 
WHERE il.TABLEID='LEAS' AND il.TABLEKEY = L.LEASID 
GROUP BY n.LEASID, N.BLDGID, n.ACTIONED, IL.TABLEKEY, IL.TABLEID, L.LEASID
HAVING N.LEASID='083468' AND
        --Use TOP 1. It should help you
       (SELECT TOP 1 MAX(il.INSLEND) FROM dbo.INSL WHERE IL.TABLEKEY=L.LEASID AND IL.TABLEID='LEAS') < '2016-04-11'
```

Comment: but i want the max value of  inslend out of all values. but u are using top 1 ?/